# How to create vectors based on coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of coordinates in the latitude-longitude format and a set of directions based on these coordinates. I can plot them as arrows using ax.quivers, but can I make a vector set that records the orientation of these quivers?

```
ax.quiver(lons,lats,dx,dy,headwidth=0.8,headlength=0,scale=35,width=0.008,
      transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Here I have the lontitudes, latitudes and the dx,dy as arrow directions. Can I extract these arrows as vectors and create an array?

Add on-I was trying to get the orientation(in degrees) of these arrows.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are the vectors centered at the center of the sphere or at (0,0) on sphere's surface?

Comment: i think it would be more straight-forward to compute the orientation from `dx` and `dy` than to try to extact it from the object `quiver` returns

Comment: What arrow vectors? Don't you have them with `lons, lat, dx,dy` already?

Comment: I had two sets of arrows like this and I was trying to calculate the angle between them. So I think it would be more convenient for the calculation if I extract them.

Comment: you're going to need to provide a lot more information. that comment seems to dramatically shift the focus of the question

Comment: basic trigonometry will get you the orientations from dx and dy (assuming you're not covering too big of an area on the globe)

Comment: So if dx, dy were obtained from sin(x), cos(x), is there a method to calculate the angle(x) reversely? I know I can use np.arcsin(), np.arccos(), but what value should I put into the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your two vectors dx and dy, you can calculate the direction with:

```
dir_rad = np.arctan2(dy, dx)
```

which is in radians, so if you want it converted to degrees:

```
dir_deg = dir_rad*180/np.pi
```

Furthermore, this will be expressed with a +/- sign indicating whether the direction is in the upper or lower quadrants. For instance, -45° means lower right quadrant. If you want values in degrees ranging from 0 to 360, then use:

```
dir_360deg = (dir_deg+360)%360
```

Example:

```
x = np.arange(-10,10)
y = np.arange(-10,10)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
plt.quiver(xx,yy)

dir_360deg = (360+np.arctan2(yy,xx)*180/np.pi)%360

plt.imshow(dir_360deg)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: Quiver plot]

[image]

You can find a helpful [article](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:vectors/x9e81a4f98389efdf:component-form/a/vector-magnitude-and-direction-review) about this on KhanAcademy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is this also applicable for multiple dxs and dys? (If I want to calculate the orientation for 100 pairs of dx and dy)